# How does iCloud.com hide its source code?

Tags: html, icloud

I know you can't hide HTML / Javascript / CSS because it's run on the client side, but how does iCloud.com hide its HTML?

When I view the page source on iCloud.com I just get presented with loads of Javascript, but when I go to inspect element in Chrome I can see the HTML.

I was just curious as to how they did this.

Comment: I would bet that *a lot* of the actual markup on iCloud is dynamically generated via JavaScript and not actually served as original source.

Comment: you only need one HTML tag (script) to serve an entire site worth of content.

Comment: When you view the page source, you're looking at the source you downloaded. As David said, the source you downloaded presumably then went and generated a bunch more source client-side (and/or downloaded and displayed it via ajax, I haven't looked at the source of that particular site). You can find extensions to view the exact generated source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closer at the page source you'll see this:

```
#noscript div#container{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;min-height:500px;}
#noscript div#overlay{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;min-width:600px;min-height:550px;background:#0B080E;opacity:.84;}
#noscript div#container div.float-center-canvas{z-index:101;position:absolute;background-image:url
....
```

It seems all the markup is generated in javascript and if javascript isn't enabled they run noscript. Not that anyone would be able to use iCloud without JavaScript in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

All that javascript you see when viewing the source is responsible for generating the document that you can then inspect in developer tools once the page is loaded. Nothing is hidden; it's just that the document doesn't get generated until *after* the page is loaded.